# atomic_load/atomic_store on std::shared_ptr in VC11 - why the global spinlock?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, atomic, shared-ptr

I'm trying to understand exactly how to manage shared pointers safely with atomic operations. Turns out VC11 (Visual studio 2012) has support for C++11  and thereby can permit read/write races on std::shared_ptr.
I want to check I understood the basics, then ask something about the implementation detail of the atomic ops on std::shared_ptr in VC11.

```
std::shared_ptr<A> x, y, z;
x = std::make_shared<A>(args1);
y = std::make_shared<A>(args2);
```

Thread 1

```
std::shared_ptr<A> temp = std::atomic_load(&y);
```

Thread 2

```
std::atomic_store(&y, z);
```

Without the atomics, the race would potentially cause `temp` to end up having corrupted state, or Thread 2 could delete the A instance pointed to by the original y just as Thread 1 was attempting to copy and addref the shared_ptr, which would make it point to a "zombie" object.

My question regarding atomic_load and atomic_store in VC11:

I've noticed they use a spinlock that performs test-and-set on a global variable.
So I wondered: why not do the test-and-set on the topmost bit of the reference counter of the shared_ptr itself? that way locks on different shared_ptr's won't contend with each other. Is there a reason this was not done?

EDIT: VS implementation of `atomic_is_lock_free`. Not surprising, since it IS using a spinlock for everything. Still wondering why they couldn't make it use a shared_ptr-instance-specific lock instead of a global lock.

```
template <class _Ty> inline
bool atomic_is_lock_free(const shared_ptr<_Ty> *)
{   // return true if atomic operations on shared_ptr<_Ty> are lock-free
    return (false);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that std::atomic_is_lock_free(&some_shared_ptr) is true on your platform.

Comment: I read somewhere `shared_ptr` uses atomic operations inside. Maybe you don't need mix them togheter. Am I right?

Comment: shared_ptr uses atomic operations for incrementing and decrementing its use count. Without these atomic ops the value of the reference counter could be invalidated even by read/read races (i.e. 2 threads assigning from the same shared_ptr into a local one - and use count could increase by less than 2 under some orderings if it wasn't an atomic update. But this alone does not solve the 2 race conditions I mentioned in my post; it's a separate issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do an atomic test-and-set on the shared_ptr's ref count because the ref count is stored in the shared_ptr's control block.  By the time you got around to attempting your test-and-set, another thread could have released the last shared_ptr reference and deleted the control block from under you.

```
Thread 1                                  Thread 2
Read control block address

                                          Decrement ref count (now 0)
                                          Delete control block

Test-and-set ref count (undefined behaviour)
```

Remember that the premise here is that multiple threads are manipulating the *same* shared_ptr instance.  If each thread has its own instance (pointing to the same controlled object), then we have no issues and no need for atomic shared_ptr operations.

Comment: Your assertion is wrong, it is only true if you have a bug in your code.
Both threads are accessing a shared_ptr and the first thread is calling atomic_load on it. It should be able to rely on the fact that, for the duration of that call
the reference count of the object is at least 1. This can only not be the case if the other thread deletes the object, for example by calling reset in it. But that is a bug, because it is only allowed manipulate the shared_ptr with either atomic_store or atomic_exchange.

Comment: I apologize if my answer is unclear, but it is correct.  Consider the case where we have a global shared_ptr, P, and two threads both manipulating it.  Thread 1 tries to make a copy (shared_ptr a = P) and thread 2 tries to replace the value (P = b).  This can lead to exactly the scenario I described.

Comment: If you want to access a shared shared_ptr you need to use either use a mutex or use atomic_load and atomic_store everything else introduces a race condition. (good explanation: https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=17m13s)

Comment: I'm well aware, Rioki.  I think you're missing the point here.  The original question was about a potential implementation for atomic_shared_ptr.  What I've tried to explain here is why that implementation would not work, even with atomic loads and stores.

Answer (score 1):

Munging the top bit of the reference count would require code that deals with the reference count as a counter to ignore that top bit. That is, it would make the most common uses slower in order to provide a minor speed increase in less common cases.

Comment: Additionally, there is a C++(17?) standard design proposal for atomic_shared_ptr by Herb Sutter, and the document also explains the drawbacks of the existing approach (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4162.pdf) -- the performance consideration you describe is one of the drawbacks.